# Injecting touch event from service - Android

Tags: android, touch, android-service-binding, android-touch-event

I want to inject touch event from a service which is set to be foreground service (it keeps a notification in the notification bar). My device is rooted and my app is set as a system app. I've set the device to show touching gestures from developer options to track the process. There two problems:

1. Sometimes when I call the injection code, the touch gesture doesn't appear by the device, this means that the touch event is not being injected.
2. If the touch takes place and I see the gesture on the screen, sometimes it performs the action that is supposed to happen by the simulated touch, and sometimes it doesn't. I noticed that the value of prs (pressure being applied by the touch) is  0 if the touch is simulated one, while the prs by a normal finger touch is greater than 0. It seems that the prs needs to be > 0 for the simulated touch in order for an action to take place.

I cannot figure out why this happens, here is the injection code within the service:

```
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");//supolicy --live \"allow appdomain input_device dir { ioctl read getattr search open }\" \"allow appdomain input_device chr_file { ioctl read write getattr lock append open }\"");
                    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
                    String cmd = "/system/bin/input tap " + xPos + " " + yPos +"\n";


                    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
//                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "***INJECTION DONE ***", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
              //      toast.show();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                   // Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "INJECTION ERROR !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                  //  toast.show();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    //   Log.e(" ", e.getStackTrace().toString());
                }

            }
        });
t.start();
```

How can I solve this problem? Any help is appreciated.